# How to create a JTextField that will show history of what I type on it?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm new in Java and still learning on it. Is there someone could give me a code or tutorial about `JTextField` that will record and show the history of what I type. Just like a text field in html.

Comment: Where and when should the history be shown? Are you referring to the way browsers will show you past form data when the field names match?

Comment: Take a look at SwingX's AutoComplete support

Comment: Yes sir @dlev. Is there any way to do that in java?

Answer (score 0):

initialize an array 
and then add an actionkeypressed to jtextfield 
and add the elements to the array for every key pressed(whateva u type)..
and display that array into whichever element you want 
try yourself..this instead of watching the code :)